# How to Connect two variables that are the same but in different classes?

Tags: c#, class, variables

Okay I'm making some sort of database where I have 4 classes program.cs, athlete.cs, event.cs and venue.cs. One of the methods they want me to include is to search for the athlete, as well as displaying the event name and venue name. This has to be done with all the variables being private.

So I was wondering if there is anyway to have the event name variable in the athlete class connect to the event name in the event class.

Athlete Class

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

class Athlete
{
    private string firstname, lastname, address, phonenumber;
    private List<Event> eventlist = new List<Event>();
    private Event athleteEvent;

    public string athleteFirstname
    {
        get
        {
            return firstname;
        }
        set
        {
            firstname = value;
        }
    }

    public string athleteLastname
    {
        get
        {
            return lastname;
        }
        set
        {
            lastname = value;
        }
    }
    public string athleteAddress
    {
        get
        {
            return address;
        }
        set
        {
            address = value;
        }
    }
    public string athletePhonenumber
    {
        get
        {
            return phonenumber;
        }
        set
        {
            phonenumber = value;
        }
    }

    public Event eventA
    {
        get
        {
            return athleteEvent;
        }
        set
        {
            athleteEvent = eventlist[0].eventName;
        }

    }
}
```

Event Class

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

class Event
{
    private string name, date, time, venueEvent;
    private double fee;
    private List<Athlete> athletes = new List<Athlete>();


    public void addAthlete(Athlete a)
    {
        athletes.Add(a);// adds the athletes towards this class
    }

    public void displayAthletes()// method used for displaying athlete when requested
    {
        foreach (Athlete a in athletes) //Constructor
        {
            Console.WriteLine(a.athleteFirstname);
            Console.WriteLine(a.athleteLastname);
        }
    }

    public string eventName
    {
        get
        {
            return name;
        }
        set
        {
            name = value;
        }
    }
    public string eventDate
    {
        get
        {
            return date;
        }
        set
        {
            date = value;
        }
    }

    public string eventTime
    {
        get
        {
            return time;
        }
        set
        {
            time = value;
        }
    }

    public double eventFee
    {
        get
        {
            return fee;
        }
        set
        {
            fee = value;
        }
    }

    public string eventVenue
    {
        get
        {
            return venueEvent;
        }
        set
        {
            venueEvent = value;
        }
    }
}
```

This is my search method

```
#region Search Athlete
    static void searchAthlete()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter which athlete you would like to find");
        string searchChoice = Convert.ToString(Console.ReadLine());

        for(int i = 0; i < athleteClass.ToArray().Length;i++) // goes through the athletes class to the end
        {
            if (searchChoice == athleteClass[i].athleteFirstname) // checks to see what has been entered matches any of the data in the athlete class
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Athlete First Name: " + athleteClass[i].athleteFirstname);
                Console.WriteLine("Athlete Last Name:  " + athleteClass[i].athleteLastname);
                Console.WriteLine("Event Name: " + athleteClass[i].eventA);
                Console.WriteLine("Venue Name: " + eventClass[i].eventVenue);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("No record was found");
            }
            //for (int e = 0; e < 2; e++)
            //{
            //    if (athleteClass[e].eventA == eventClass[e].eventName) // checks 
            //    {
            //        Console.WriteLine("Event name: " + eventClass[e].eventName);
            //    }
            //    for (int v = 0; v < 2; v++)
            //    {
            //        if (eventClass[v].eventVenue == venueClass[v].venueName)
            //        {
            //            Console.WriteLine("Venue Name: " + venueClass[v].venueName);
            //        }
            //    }
            //}

        } 
    }
    #endregion
```

Comment: Is this homework? If so, it should be tagged as such.

Comment: What do you mean with `connect` ?

Comment: Didn't know there was a homework tag.

Comment: Well the athlete must be in an event. I gave the athlete the event that they participate in by console input. But the problem is when I search for the athlete I must also show the event name that the athlete participates in and the venue where the event is held.

Answer (score 0):

For every Athlete you have a list of Events as denoted by your code. When they add a new Athlete they should be able to add a list of Events like {event1, event2...etc} at the console. In your search you just have to call the Athlete object, Athlete.GetEventsList() and print out each event associated with this Athlete. I'll do pseudocode so you learn on your own.

**Edit**
First of all you need to save Events for each Athlete. So you need a Set/Get method to save incoming Events from the console for the particular Athlete. Once you have a list of Events for the Athlete then you can do this.

```
for each Athlete a in ListOfAthletes
{
  get eventList for a
  for each event in eventList
   get event Name
   //print out athlete Name and event Name
}
```

Comment: well the athletes can only be assigned to one event at the moment. Yeah when you add an athlete you enter 1 or 2 for the events.

Comment: See edit. You need to save the events, otherwise how will you even access the events for the athlete?

Comment: Yea I just saw that. So you're all set.

Comment: Unfortunately my search method doesn't display the event name and venue name. It does show the athletes name and lastname

Comment: Scratch what I said, you DO NOT have a method that saves Events in your Athlete class. Your method Event eventA does not ADD to the `eventList[0]`. You are GETTING `eventList[0]` in the Set but you really need to put something in there first. `eventList[0].Add(value)` then you can write `athleteEvent = eventList[0].name`

Comment: Yes I do get what you are saying I thought I needed to do that in my athlete class. So I gave this a try and the `code eventList[0].Add(value)` doesn't work as I would need to have a contructor method, but when I make the method into that the get and set doesn't work.